# getting case when to work inside a formula

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a custom column in sql that works:

```
,case
    when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3
      then '1'
    else extract(day from now() - 2)
  end as MTD
```

and then I wanted to have another column that would work off of that query but when I realized I couldn't quite query on that without saving/naming it etc I tried to get the case when in the formula thinking it would work the same way

the original query that I wanted to have next would have been:

```
,(combo.autotradercom_vdp + combo.carscom_vdp) / min(MTD, combo.age) as VDP/MTD
```

so instead of that I built this which by my logic should work but is not:

```
,(combo.autotradercom_vdp + combo.carscom_vdp) / min(case when (extract(day from now () - 2)) < 3 then '1' else extract (day from now() - 2) end, combo.age) as VDP/MTD
```

I'm getting a ERROR: syntax error at or near "#" and I know the problem is with min() part of the query but can't seem to understand where the problem is.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

added whole query

```
--work in brogress, will automate inventory review excel doc
select
  case
    when combo.total_repairs < 1
      then 'None'
    when combo.total_repairs < (combo.guaranteed_price * 4) / 100
      then 'Lo'
    when combo.total_repairs between(combo.guaranteed_price * 4) / 100
    and (
      combo.guaranteed_price * 8
    )
    / 100
      then 'Med'
    else 'Hi'
  end as Repair_Tier
  , case
    when combo.list_price < combo.guaranteed_price
      then '0'
    else combo.seller_upside_percentage
  end as Seller_Upside
  , combo.days_to_expiration as Days_remaining_on_contract
  , case
    when(combo.deposit + combo.needs_repairs + combo.going_to_auction + combo.in_transit + combo.hold_for_trade_in + combo.hold_for_financing) > 0
    or left(combo.paperwork_missing, 3) = 'Yes'
      then concat('Reserved - ', case when combo.deposit > 0 then 'Deposit' when combo.needs_repairs > 0 then 'Needs Repairs' when combo.going_to_auction > 0 then 'Going to Auction' when combo.in_transit > 0 then 'In Transit' when combo.hold_for_trade_in > 0 then 'Hold for Trade-In' when combo.hold_for_financing > 0 then 'Hold for Financing' else concat('Paperwork Missing - ', combo.paperwork_missing_reason) end)
    else ''
  end as Reserved
  , case
    when combo.future_test_drives > 0
      then combo.future_test_drives
    else '0'
  end as Future_Test_Drives
  , case
    when combo.recent_test_drives > 0
      then combo.recent_test_drives
    else '0'
  end as Recent_Test_Drivescase
  , case
    when combo.recent_buyer_leads > 0
      then combo.recent_buyer_leads
    else '0'
  end as Recent_Buyer_Leads
  --MTD-2
  , case
    when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3
      then 1
    else extract(day from now() - 2)
  end as MTD 
  , (combo.autotradercom_vdp + combo.carscom_vdp) / min (case
    when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3
      then '1'
    else extract(day from now() - 2)
  end, combo.age) as VDP/MTD
from
  [combo]
```

Comment: Please show your entire query.

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using; (2) a column alias cannot be used in a `select` (or `where` or `group by` etc.) corresponding to the `select` where it is defined.

Comment: Tagged and updated

Comment: I'm not sure about postgresql, but in tsql, you can simply do it like this (for example): `1 + case when x then 1 when y then 2 else 3 end + 5` in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

```
, (combo.autotradercom_vdp + combo.carscom_vdp) / min (case
    when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3
      then '1' -- why a string instead of an INT?
    else extract(day from now() - 2)
  end, combo.age) as VDP/MTD
                  #2:^^^^^^^ this alias will result in an error, too, must be quoted
     ^^^^^^^^^^^ #1: where is this coming from?
```

This should work:

```
, (combo.autotradercom_vdp + combo.carscom_vdp) / min (case
    when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3
      then 1
    else extract(day from now() - 2)
  end) as "VDP/MTD"
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using math instead of sql formula to get min number out of two as the min can only reference columns

Solution:

```
, cast(
    (combo.autotradercom_vdp + combo.carscom_vdp) / (0.5 * (((case when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3 then 1 else extract(day from now() - 2) end) + (
            case
              when combo.age > 0
                then combo.age
              else 1
            end
          )
        )
        - abs(
          (
            case
              when(extract(day from now() - 2)) < 3
                then 1
              else extract(day from now() - 2)
            end
          )
          - (
            case
              when combo.age > 0
                then combo.age
              else 1
            end
          )
        )
      )
    )
    as int
  )
  as "VDP/DL"
```